# How can I evenly sample an array in Python, in order, according to a sample rate?

Tags: python

I have `array_large` and `array_small`. I need to evenly sample from `array_large` so that I end up with an array the same size as `array_small`. (Or in other words, I need a representative, downsized version of `array_large` to match up with `array_small`.)

As a super-trivial example, if `array_small = [0, 1]` and `array_large = [0, 1, 2, 3]` I would expect `sample = [0, 2]` or `sample = [1, 3]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's imagine `array_small` is 30 items and `array_large` is 100.

```
array_small = [i for i in range(30)]
array_large = [i for i in range(100)]

sample_rate = len(array_large) / len(array_small)
```

In that case our `sample_rate` is `3.333...` which means we want about every 3rd item, but sometimes every 4th item. Since the `sample_rate` is a float we can account for that with `math.floor()` and use the mod operator on the array index:

```
import math

array_large_sample = [
    num for i, num in enumerate(array_large)
    if math.floor(i % sample_rate) == 0
]
print(array_large_sample)
print(len(array_large_sample))

OUTPUT:
[0, 4, 7, 11, 14, 17, 21, 24, 27, 31, 34, 37, 41, 44, 47, 51, 54, 57, 61, 64, 67, 71, 74, 77, 81, 84, 87, 91, 94, 97]
30
```